# Using WCF with Excel 2003?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, excel

Does anyone know or can find some sample code showing how to call a WCF service using Excel 2003?

Answer (score 2):

This article targets accessing [Web Services in Excel Using Visual Studio Tools for the Microsoft Office System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/aa168471.aspx), and the information should apply similarly to a WCF service.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the perfect winner for you, it's probably going to be difficult.  Things got a lot better developing for Office 2007.  But, given that, you should check out [Visual Studio Tools for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/default.aspx).  [Here are some examples using VSTO with Excel 2003](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=f220681f-fbe5-4ad1-b517-229079a16cb4&displaylang=en).  [Here is an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163292.aspx) on how to call WCF from an Office 2007 application.  You should be able to adopt that with some success.  GL. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call WCF web services from Excel2003 and you dont want to use VSTO, you need a COM compatible option (No .Net).

Although it is Tooooootally deprecated (and uncool) you can achieve this using a basicHttpBinding on the server and the 
[Soap Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C943C0DD-CEEC-4088-9753-86F052EC8450&displaylang=en)

If you dont want to do that, you may be able to do the calls using a .Net assembly and use COM Interop to call it from Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at using the WCF Service Moniker which lets you invoke a WCF Service from VBA without installing anything on the Excel client machine other than the .NET Framework.

```
Dim addr As String
addr = "service:mexAddress=""net.tcp://localhost:7891/Test/WcfService1/Service1/Mex"","
addr = addr + "address=""net.tcp://localhost:7891/Test/WcfService1/Service1/"","
addr = addr + "contract=""IService1"", contractNamespace=""http://tempuri.org/"","
addr = addr + "binding=""NetTcpBinding_IService1"",bindingNamespace=""http://tempuri.org/"""

Dim service1 As Object
Set service1 = GetObject(addr)

MsgBox service1.GetData(12)
```

I've written out a [complete step-by-step example](http://damianblog.com/2009/07/05/excel-wcf/).

/Damian

Answer (score 0):

REST services also  work quite nicely with Excel. 
If you use the "WebHttpBinding" you can import the data to excel using File -> Open or via Import External data -> Xml.
Isn't quite perfect with 2003 though (much better with 2007).